# ASP.NET Chart Control Formatting

Tags: asp.net, coding-style, charts, asp.net-charts

I need help trying to style the asp.net chart control. I have a doughnut chart that I need to style:

- The background of the doughnut to be transparent so the underlying gradient shows through.
- I'd like to move the legend to the bottom below the chart ... that way I can make a tall/thin chart

This is what it currently looks like. And I haven't found the right combinations of settings to make it happen. Thanks!

[image: My current chart]
<sub>(source: [codecube.net](http://codecube.net/bloguploads/regionsimage.png))</sub>

Comment: try http://raphaeljs.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1 - Transparency

```
Chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

2 - Legend

```
// Set legend docking
Chart.Legends["Default"].Docking = LegendDocking.Bottom;
```

Comment: the docking one worked a charm, however, my chartareas collection is empty. Adding one and setting the backcolor property on that just results in an empty chart area underneath my chart :-(

Comment: Have you tried Chart.BackColor = Color.Transparent? Try to play with properties of the chart that contain the word Color.